# Working with promises, doing a save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I have the following cloud function returning immediately, with promise full-filled but without doing its job. Can any one see why?

```
function myFunction(newValArray)
{
    console.log("Entered myFunction.");
    var query,classPromise;
    query = new Parse.Query("myClass");

    classPromise = (query.find().then
     (function(result) {
     result[0].set("myField", result[0].get("myField")+1);
     result[0].save(null,{}).then
     (function() {
     console.log("1)newValArray:"+newValArray.length.toString());
     newValArray.push(result[0].get("myField"));
     console.log("2)newValArray:"+newValArray.length.toString());
     return Parse.Promise.as();
     });
     }));

    return Parse.Promise.when(classPromise);
}
```

If I then use this code for :

```
myFunction(newLTR).then
(function() {
 console.log("myFunction FULL-FILLED.");
 }
```

I can see the messages `"Entered myFunction."` and `"myFunction FULL-FILLED."` in the logs.
 But I never see `"1)newValArray:..."` neither do I see `"2)newValArray:..."`
I have also checked that the passed parameter has not been processed as expected.

If I replace myFunction with the following version, it doesn't make any difference:

```
 function myFunction(newValArray)
{
    console.log("Entered myFunction.");
    var query,classPromise;
    query = new Parse.Query("Configuration");

    classPromise = (query.find().then
                  (function(result) {
                   result[0].set("myField", result[0].get("myField")+1);
                   result[0].save(null,{
                                      success:function(configRcd) {
                                      console.log("1)newValArray:"+newValArray.length.toString());
                                      newValArray.push(configRcd.get("myField"));
                                      console.log("2)newValArray:"+newValArray.length.toString());
                                      return Parse.Promise.as();
                                      },
                                      error:function(error) {
                                      console.log("Something went wrong in incrementLastTouchReference.");
                                      }});
                   }));

    return Parse.Promise.when(classPromise);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's unreadable indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a terrible way to write your promises. The whole reason you want to use promises in the first place, is so you can chain callbacks. In your example it's the worst of both worlds, the complexity of promises but you're still nesting.

The second issue is that you really need to place a final error handler. Any errors emitted right now might just disappear. *always* end with a `catch`.

I rewrote your first function to *correctly* do promises, but I can't guarantee if there's not something else wrong. Hopefully it helps you along your way:

```
function myFunction(newValArray)
{
    console.log("Entered myFunction.");
    var query,classPromise;

    query = new Parse.Query("myClass");

    classPromise = query.find()
     .then(function(result) {
       result[0].set("myField", result[0].get("myField")+1);
       return result[0].save(null,{});
     }).then(function() {

         console.log("1)newValArray:" + newValArray.length.toString());
         newValArray.push(result[0].get("myField"));
         console.log("2)newValArray:"+newValArray.length.toString());
         return Parse.Promise.as();

     }).then(function(result) {

         // I added this third then clause. You were returning
         // Parse.Promise.as() so presumably you wanted to do something
         // with that. Before this then clause it got discarded, with my
         // change the result of Parse.Promise.as() is thrown in the
         // 'result' argument in this function.

     }).catch(function(err) {

         // If an error is thrown in any part of the change, it will
         // bubble to this final catch statement.
         // Do something with err! Log it or whatever ;)

     })

    return Parse.Promise.when(classPromise);
}
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. Thanks a lot!
Now it finally works.

Comment: "*always end with a `.catch`*" - not exactly. You'll want to end every promise *chain* with `.catch`, yes, but you don't want to put it *everywhere*. Since `myFunction` does return the promise, I don't see a reason to put it here.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't realize that `Parse.Promise.when` returns another promise. Makes sense then!

Comment: I am not sure, I quite get this catch stuff yet. Though I understand the idea of the catch. I'd like to see a simple and concrete example on how to use it in Parse cloud code.

Comment: Personally I _strongly_ feel that anybody that uses promises, should at least once attempt to write a promise object as well. Only if you can successfully pull that off I feel you will get a good understanding of how promises work.